# Try-Catch Error Message Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql, error-handling, triggers, foreign-keys, raiserror

I'm trying to write a query that instead of the error:

> INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint...`

I can have my own error. Something like:

> < Value > does not exist on < table_name >

```
 TEST TABLE1:                       TEST TABLE2

 Col1 PK tinyint                    Col2 PK tinyint
 Col2 FK tinyint
```

I made the following trigger as a test:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CHECK_INSERT]
FOR INSERT
ON TABLE1
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @loop AS TINYINT
     DECLARE @col1 AS TINYINT
     DECLARE @col2 AS TINYINT
     SELECT @loop = MIN (col1) FROM INSERTED
     SELECT @col1 = col1 FROM INSERTED WHERE col1 = @loop
     SELECT @col2 = col2 FROM INSERTED WHERE col1 = @loop

     IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM TABLE2 WHERE col2 = @col2) 
     AND ERROR_NUMBER() = 547
     BEGIN
          RAISERROR('%s does not exists on Table2', 16, 1, CAST(@col2 AS VARCHAR(3))
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     END
END
```

How can I handle this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add insert statement in try/catch, but I think at first you need INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger.